# When doing body paint, do you cover up bolt holes?

Tags: paint

I'm about to [Herculine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002TDUW4) some body parts on a Jeep, and I'm wondering if you normally when doing body work cover up threaded bolt holes or paint over them? Is it difficult to put in a bolt if there is paint in the hole?

Herculine is rubber brush/roll on paint. Is it any different?

Comment: Do not paint over bolt holes.  You will regret the pain you create for yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about holes with threads or just blank holes?  Threads will cause you problems; blank holes, no problem.

Comment: Painted bolt holes is nothing running a tap through them won't fix.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the bolt hole tolerances you start out with, the paint may prevent the bolt from screwing into the bolt hole.

It's not that difficult to avoid the problem - plug in a rag, tissue paper or something that acts as a barrier to the paint. Once the paint is dry, pull it out to leave thread that is unscathed.

Answer (score 0):

How about taping off the hole with painters or masking tape then, remove the excess tape by using a razor blade and cutting around the  outside

Comment: Seems like if you cut away the tape so that only the part covering the hole is left there would be nothing left to hold the tape in place.